# How to create postgresql's sequences in Alembic

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using `alembic` to maintain my tables. At the same time, I update my models using the declarative way.

This is one the alembic's table:

```
op.create_table(
    'groups',
    Column('id', Integer, Sequence('group_id_seq'), primary_key=True),
    Column('name', Unicode(50)),
    Column('description', Unicode(250)),
)
```

And the model is like the following:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('group_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(50))
    description = Column(Unicode(250))

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.description = description
        self.name = name
```

You can see, I'm using the `Sequence` in both the alembic migration and in the declarative model.

But I have noticed that when using PostgreSQL (v9.1) no sequences are created by alembic, and so the models fail to create instances since they will use the `nextval(<sequence name>)` clause.

So, how can I create my alembic migrations so that the sequences are truly generated in postgresql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a hint at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issue/60/autogenerate-for-sequences-as-well-as#comment-4100402

Following the `CreateSequence` found in the previous link I still have to jump through several hoops to make my migrations works in SQLite and PostgreSQL. Currently I have:

```
def dialect_supports_sequences():
    return op._proxy.migration_context.dialect.supports_sequences


def create_seq(name):
    if dialect_supports_sequences():
       op.execute(CreateSequence(Sequence(name)))
```

And then call the `create_seq` whenever I need it.

Is this the best practice?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to do it right now.

        `from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence, CreateSequence
        op.execute(CreateSequence(Sequence("some_sequence"))`

Comment: I'm unable to view that bitbucket URL.

Comment: Same here. Could you post the related content here?

Comment: `op.get_context().dialect.supports_sequences` seems more stable than using `_proxy`.

Comment: Just a bit of extra info as I had trouble finding this myself. If you want to specify a start value for your sequence do this: `op.execute(CreateSequence(Sequence('tablename_id_seq', 1000)))`. Also, note that the sequence declaration must be placed `before` the table creation statement in your Alembic versions file.

Answer (score 22):

Just add following to your model:

```
field_seq = Sequence('groups_field_seq')
field = Column(Integer, field_seq, server_default=field_seq.next_value())
```

And add following to your migration file (before creating table):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import Sequence, CreateSequence
op.execute(CreateSequence(Sequence('groups_field_seq')))
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but I am assuming this works based on the amount of upvotes. I think there might be a better way to do it but I am unsure at this time. The reason I think so is based from [this alembic documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/autogenerate.html#autogenerating-custom-operation-directives).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I got your question right but as nobody else chose to answer, here is how I get perfectly normal `id`s:

Alembic:

```
op.create_table('event',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
```

The class:

```
class Event(SQLADeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
```

Comment: But you are not using the `Sequence` stuff I mention. I don't think PostgreSQL requires it, but it will create it automatically when autoincrement is used. However, I think is an issue that must be addressed since the SQLAlchemy docs "promote" the usage of Sequence as a fool-proof way to have auto-incrementing ids in all engines...

Comment: I know I didn't use it. I didn't see the benefit of using it especially when it doesn't work. I checked your code and didn't see any "start the sequence at 100" or "use only even numbers" special stuff, so I thought the default behaviour should do just fine. Sometimes others stating the obvious was what helped me get back on track.

Comment: Not working for postgres or anything else by MySQL: `autoincrement – set the AUTO_INCREMENT flag of the column; currently understood by the MySQL dialect.` - https://alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column.params.autoincrement

Comment: @zzzeek described this answer with the following "the answer you refer to is completely wrong".

Comment: @MarcoSulla's link is broken. Here's an archived version of that page: https://web.archive.org/web/20160611064121/http://alembic.readthedocs.io:80/en/latest/ops.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently and here is how i solved it.

```
op.execute("create sequence SEQUENCE_NAME")
```

I ran the above command inside the upgrade function and for the downgrade run the below code inside the downgrade function respectively.

```
op.execute("drop sequence SEQUENCE_NAME")
```